# How do I load offline google map/earth vrt files as a backdrop in qgis

Tags: qgis-plugins, google-earth, tilecache, gdalbuildvrt

I was trying to follow the process : [saving-google-earth-location](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7426/saving-google-earth-location-openlayers-plugin-in-quantum-gis)

in order to cache google maps/earth offline for digitizing, but I am fairly new to qgis. When I try to add the vrt file as a raster in qgis I get nothing but a blank image. I also noticed that pyramiding gave me an error which I suspect is because of the resolution. In addition if I wanted to load the vrt as a backdrop/base map does it not require a bunch of tiles loaded to create an image mosaic? I am working in Windows so I would prefer to not have to run some gdal commands in the command prompt.

I'm also not so sure how to use tile caching and I would prefer the easiest way possible without having to standup any wms type of server.

*I know its against the terms of service.